# Is there a standard ratio fixed for the dimensions of arms of the plain Cross?

Tags: cross, standards, universal

The plain Cross is perhaps the most frequently used symbol on the earth. One can see a distinct pattern in the dimensions of the horizontal and vertical beams of the Cross . Many years ago, I heard that the ideal ratio of the length of the vertical arm and each of the horizontal arms measured from the junction is 2:3. To elaborate, if the vertical arm above the junction is two feet long, each of the horizontal arms should be of three feet. One is not sure if a proportion is fixed for the vertical beam running downwards from the junction. The question is :Is there a standard ratio fixed for the dimensions of arms  of the plain Cross ? If there is one, does it have a historical backdrop, or is it just a matter of aesthetic considerations ? PS: a typical example of aesthetic considerations is the dimensions of National Flags. The Indian National Flag has the prescribed ratio of 2:3 for width and length. The American Flag has 1:1.9 .The ratio is determined  by the features of the flag and the prospects of the best look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a standard ratio fixed for the dimensions of hands of the plain Cross?**

The short answer is No. there is no fixed ratio for the the vertical beam in junction With the horizontal stake. The 2:3 ratio is nice but not a fixed measurement in any artist school that I am aware of.

> A **Latin cross** or ***crux immissa*** is a type of cross in which the vertical beam sticks above the crossbeam, with the three upper arms either equally long or with the vertical topmost arm shorter than the two horizontal arms, and always with a much longer bottom arm.
>
> If displayed upside down it is called St. Peter's Cross, because he was executed on this type of cross. When displayed sideways it is called St. Philip's cross for the same reason.
>
> Many medieval churches are designed using the Latin cross plan. When looked at from above, it takes the shape of a Latin cross. A Latin cross plan primarily contains a nave, transept, apse, and narthex. - [Latin Cross](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_cross)

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer relates to what Balaam saw the third time he was taken to “a high place” by Balak to curse Israel, where he prophesied over them.

I would have to work it out again from the maps, but I believe he is facing west that third time, which would also be the direction one would go when entering into the Tabernacle and then the Holy of Holies. If we took out the spacing that was added for the words “man”, “ox”, etc.; then we would have a cross with specific dimensions. I initially balked because the two cross-arms differ in length by 4%, but why would we think the actual cross was perfectly symmetrical in this world?

[image: Graphic of The Camp of Israel with the totals of each tribe and group within the camp]

There’s a writeup about it at [The Tabernacle of Moses and the Cross](https://graceandtruth.me/2014/11/18/the-tabernacle-of-moses-and-the-cross/#:%7E:text=The%20Tabernacle%20was%20in%20the,Dan%2C%20Asher%20and%20Naphtali%20camped).

Numbers 24:2-9

> <sup>**2**</sup> And Balaam lifted up his eyes, and he saw Israel abiding in his tents according to their tribes; and the spirit of God came upon him. <sup>**3**</sup> And he took up his parable, and said, Balaam the son of Beor hath said, and the man whose eyes are open hath said: <sup>**4**</sup> He hath said, which heard the words of God, which saw the vision of the Almighty, falling into a trance, but having his eyes open: <sup>**5**</sup> How goodly are thy tents, O Jacob, and thy tabernacles, O Israel! <sup>**6**</sup> As the valleys are they spread forth, as gardens by the river's side, as the trees of lign aloes which the Lord hath planted, and as cedar trees beside the waters. <sup>**7**</sup> He shall pour the water out of his buckets, and his seed shall be in many waters, and his king shall be higher than Agag, and his kingdom shall be exalted. <sup>**8**</sup> God brought him forth out of Egypt; he hath as it were the strength of an unicorn: he shall eat up the nations his enemies, and shall break their bones, and pierce them through with his arrows. <sup>**9**</sup> He couched, he lay down as a lion, and as a great lion: who shall stir him up? Blessed is he that blesseth thee, and cursed is he that curseth thee.

Comment: @agarza thank you for the edits, especially this one, which required more format changes. Haven’t been on here awhile. 

Comment: Not sure what’s missing in this answer. Is it that people dislike missler on some other topics? Well I do too. But is pretty straightforward what’s being done here. Requires no source but the Bible and its numbers for the tribes.

Comment: Al Brown, let us keep in mind that Romans made the cross to hang Jesus as a subject of public mockery with the hands and legs spread out. It also provided for the signboard INRI in full in three languages. Otherwise it would have been T shaped. One wonders if the Romans had the arithmetics of OT in mind while shaping the cross.